# How to translate Xamarin Xaml IValueConverter into C#?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, ivalueconverter

Can you please help me translate this Xamarin xaml into c#?

```
BackgroundColor="{Binding IconColor, Converter={StaticResource LocalHexColorFromStringConverter}}"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobjectextensions.setbinding?view=xamarin-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate it by `MyBtn.SetBinding(Button.BackgroundColorProperty, "IconColor", BindingMode.OneTime, new LocalHexColorFromStringConverter()) ;`

I make a test with Button's background color.

```
   Button MyBtn = new Button();
   MyBtn.Text = "test";
   MyBtn.SetBinding(Button.BackgroundColorProperty, "IconColor", BindingMode.OneTime, new LocalHexColorFromStringConverter()) ;
   Content = MyBtn;
```

Here is `LocalHexColorFromStringConverter.cs`

```
  public class LocalHexColorFromStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Color.FromHex((string)value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

> Can I ask what the difference is between "new LocalHexColorFromStringConverter()" and "converter: LocalHexColorFromStringConverter()" ?

Do you mean "new LocalHexColorFromStringConverter()" and "converter: LocalHexColorFromStringConverter"?

If so, they are same, `converter: LocalHexColorFromStringConverter` is wirte type in Xaml ,  `converter:` is prefix, it explains the specific path of this class, If you want to call it from any pages, you need to write it in the `App.xaml`.

For example, you add add it in the App.xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:OAuthGoogleDemo"
             x:Class="OAuthGoogleDemo.App">
    <Application.Resources>
       
       <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:LocalHexColorFromStringConverter x:Key="HexColorFromStringConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
        
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then use it in the Mainpage.xaml with `Converter={StaticResource HexColorFromStringConverter}}"`

Comment: Can I ask what the difference is between "new LocalHexColorFromStringConverter()" and "converter: LocalHexColorFromStringConverter()" ?  I guess I learned to create an instance in App.Xaml, then call it from any page.... is that a typical workflow?